# exception handling in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, exception

I made a Mysql stored procedure to delete a client from a table, this procedure uses as parameter the id of the client that's going to be deleted, I want to get an error message in return if the client's id was not found in the table.
my procedure looks like this:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `delete_client`(in cod varchar(8))
 BEGIN
 -- the code
 END
```

I'm familiar with the oracle way of handling this error (if SQL%NOTFOUND Then raise..) but i have no idea how to do it in mysql. also, I'm calling this procedure from a php file so how do i get to echo the error message from the exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at here for error handling in stored procedures:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/